# How to call a $resource in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following codes:

The controlles has:

```
    $scope.buscarTermos = function (termo, campo){
        if(termo.length>1){
           $scope.legendas = Legenda.query({'termo':'Luiz', 'campo':'legenda'}, function(todo) {
        });
        }
    }
```

And the factory

```
 .factory('Legenda', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource(apiDomain + 'AutoComplete/', {
                    'termo': '@Termo',
                    'campo': '@Campo'
        });
    }])
```

How to make the $buscarTermos work? When I call it nothing happens to the $scope.legendas it just load a promise... How do I execute the promise?

Comment: where have you defined your apiDomain?

Comment: http://localhost:55399/teste/api

Comment: The code has a $q.all([$scope.legendas.promise ...
If I put  $scope.legendas = Legenda.query({'termo':'Luiz', 'campo':'legenda'}); before the buscarTermos it works, but I want to call it on demand not just when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer!

```
$scope.buscarTermos = function (termo, campo){
        if(termo.length>1){
           $scope.legendas = Legenda.query({'termo':'Luiz', 'campo':'legenda'});

           $q.all([$scope.legendas.$promise]).then( function(result) {
                        $scope.legendas = result;
                        console.log($scope.legendas);
           })
        }
    }
```

I just needed a $q inside! Thanks Guys!